# Should we implement tags for Seasons of TV Shows?

Tags: discussion, tags, spoilers

One aspect of this site is that sometimes questions can lead to spoilers. It's an inherent danger to any topic regarding a movie or tv series. With movies it's fairly easy to avoid, as each movie has its own tag, even amongst movie franchises,  and questions regarding events are usually tagged.

While we try to hide spoilers in titles, sometimes this means the titles are so generic that someone half way through a TV series will end up reading, or attempt to answer it.

If we used tags for Seasons, like we would individual movies in a series or franchise, we could avoid this. While a bit meta, this may alleviate some issues with user participation. (I.e., someone can participate on questions regarding seasons they have seen while ignoring seasons they have not). And it's functionally the equivalent of movie series tags. For example, someone can avoid Star Wars Episode 7/The Force Awakens spoilers by ignoring that specific tag, while still seeing other Star Wars questions. The same can't currently be done with Game of Thrones, or Agents of Shield, or any other long running series.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you proposing a `game-of-thrones-season-3` tag or a `season-3` tag to go with the `game-of-thrones` tag?

Comment: Not sure. Hence the discussion

Comment: I'm not sure if this is needed. I can't imagine someone being an expert in season-2 of Breaking Bad, but being clueless about season-1 or any other season of it. I get the logic, but think this goes to a level of granularity that just isn't needed.

Comment: And most of the time it's not as clear-cut anyway. The 1-tag solution looks awful and splinters tags up too much and the 2-tag solution is simply not of use for spoiler-hiding and bound to be used completely inconsistently.

Answer (score 6):

Tags are designed as a means to categorize groups of related questions based on a typical users' interests. Tags are not really intended to enumerate every possible detail about a question.

It is hard to imagine there is a large audience who are categorically interested in questions "just about season 3". I would suggest that making tags this granular would be a wasted effort and might even hamper users' ability to *easily* find interesting content.

Comment: Most questions only have two or three tags, so it would be displacing anything, and the search allows you to pair tags, so you could search for [tag:game-of-thrones] [tag:season-2] for example, which would in no way be consider **hampering**

Comment: In fact, you can link to both tags at the same time [tag:game-of-thrones+realism] so it's even easier to find interesting content.